# Do I have to enable authentication in Mongo for a self-managed server?

Tags: security, mongodb

Up to this point, my server was a development environment. As such, authentication was off in MongoDb.
It's now time to get into production. I looked up how to do authentication. However, given the following circumstances:

- No remote connection is allowed. I use a tunnel to administer it.
- There will be 4 apps running, all controlled by us
- We have a number of automatic db scripts in place for deployment
- This is our own server

Does it actually make any sense turning on security, other than looking good to management? Especially considering that:

- We would create one user per app
- Each server would need the password in the source code to connect to the db
- Some of the admin scripts are run automatically. So, those scripts would also include the password

I guess having to go around and fish DB passwords might make the life of an intruder a *little* harder (they will need to figure out where the apps are, and that might take 10 minutes or so, rather than just dumping mongo's DB). But is this one really the only real reason?

Comment: You know there are more methods of authentication, other than by username and password? You might want to look into [x.509 certificate, or kerberos, or ldap authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/)

Comment: When you say "no remote connection is allowed" - how do your 4 apps connect? I hope you're not intending to run them all on the same box in production?

Answer (score 2):

I expect that [this developer also thought](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/02/creepy-iot-teddy-bear-leaks-2-million-parents-and-kids-voice-messages/) that enabling authentication would not be needed. Look at how well that worked out for them...

And that is just one example of [many thousands](https://cispa.saarland/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MongoDB_documentation.pdf) unsecured Mongo instances found online.

> Does it actually make any sense turning on security, other than looking good to management?

I'm sure that your manager is a firm believer in *"there is is no such thing as bad publicity"* but making headlines because your lack of basic security measures exposed all your company's records and customer data is usually a *"career limiting move"*.

That is a polite way of saying that not taking basic security measures is considered negligent and incompetent.

Comment: Your points are totally fair. But... the database _isn't_ online, and regardless of this, the passwords would still be easy to find. I guess it will still raise the bar...

Comment: The thing with bad security practices is that it makes life *slightly* easier during initial development.  Correcting for them after you have a nearly finished product is immensely more difficult than taking security into account early on. The second thing is that now you may run your whole stack on a single server, you may not always do so. `-|-` Your remark: *"the password in the source code"* makes me cringe too, you should have a configuration file that you load where you can change options and settings without modifying your code...

Comment: It *is* in a config file. But the difference is pointless. It's in the clear somewhere, as it needs to be. My problem is that while I agree with all of your points (regardless of the way you are putting them across), I am asking if there is a REAL reason why a db server that is NOT listening to a TCP port should be password protected -- especially when the password would need to be in the clear SOMEWHERE in the config files used to running the client programs